# How does one show that there exists some $z \in X$ such that $f(z) = z$ under certain circumstances?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In a previous exercise, one was asked to show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n > 0}$ in $X$ (with $(X,d)$ a non-empty, complete metric space) in which we have $d(x_n,x_{n+1}) \leq \theta d(x_{n-1} , x_n ) $, is convergent (with $0  < \theta < 1$). I did this by showing that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

In the present exercise, the following is given: $f : X \to X$ is a map such that for all $x,y \in X$ we have $d(f(x),f(y)) \leq \theta d(x,y) $, 
with $0 < \theta <1$.

One is now asked to show that there exists some $z \in X$, such that $f(z) = z$.

The following hint is given: pick some $z_0 \in X$ and consider the sequence $(z_0, f(z_0), f(f(z_0)), \dots ).)$.

The question is: how do I prove that there is some $z$ such that $f(z) = z$ ? I tried using the result of the previous exercise, but I couldn't figure out how to use it, nor do I know how to use the hint.

Comment: Sounds like banach fixpoint theorem for me, maybe you should remove the tag general topology as you do have a complete metric space

Comment: @DominicMichaelis oh ok. This exercise is given during a general topology course. I did not know how to tag it otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further HINT: Use the previous exercise to show that the sequence $\langle z_0,f(z_0),f(f(z_0)),\dots\rangle$ is Cauchy. Let $z$ be its limit. Use the continuity of $f$ to show that $f(z)=z$.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more elaborate?

Comment: @Max: Which part? That the sequence is Cauchy, or that its limit is a fixed point of $f$?

Comment: The second part: that the limit is a fixed point of $f$, using continuity.

Comment: It’s a general fact: if $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, and $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence in $X$ converging to $x$, then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $f(x)$ in $Y$. In this problem, however, the image sequence $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is just the original sequence without its first term: it’s $\langle f(z_0), f(f(z_0)),\dots\rangle$, so it has the same limit as the original sequence.

Comment: @Max: Excellent! You’re welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Putting $z_{n+1}=f(z_n)$, we find that $d(z_n,z_{n+1})\leq\theta d(z_{n-1},z_n)$ for all $n\geq 1$, so by your previous exercise, we have that the sequence of $z_n$s converges, say to $z$. What is $f(z)$, given the continuity of $f$?

Comment: Thanks. I guess this answer is equally good, since it's about the same, but I can accept just one.

Comment: Quite allright.